# Conditionally showing/hiding checkboxes within tiles in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a list of tiles dynamically generated from an API call. I have a share button in the AppBar which when I click I would like to make checkboxes appear as the trailing property in the list tile. example:

```
ListTile(
  title: Text('fetchedData.title'),
  trailing: Checkbox()
)
```

My approach is conditionally rendering the tiles but I'm not so sure I'm doing it in the correct place. I'm using a boolean piece of state to determine whether checkboxes should display next to the tile or not.

Something else I tried is creating helper functions to build list tiles for me but not sure what it should return, if you have any tips on how to make these sorta functions please include that!

This is my code:

```
body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: pdfSnippets(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                // will have to hide the eccess snippet with overflow
                //  and have a max width to fit the trailing checkbox
                itemCount: snippets.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  // if you don't like card view, remove Card and just return ListTile
                  return checkboxStatus ? 
                  Card (
                    child: ListTile(
                      // not referencing properly
                      title: Text('${snapshot[index].body}'),
                      subtitle: Text('${snapshot[index].title}'),
                      trailing: Checkbox(
                        value: false,
                      )
                    )
                  ) : 
                  Card (  
                    child: ListTile(
                    // not referencing properly
                    title: Text('${snapshot[index].body}'),
                    subtitle: Text('${snapshot[index].title}'),
                    onLongPress: () => setCheckboxStatus(),
                    )
                  );
                }
              );
            } else {
              throw('nothing to see here');
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just make the `CheckBox` conditional like this to make your code look simpler:

```
ListTile(
// not referencing properly
title: Text('body'),
subtitle: Text('title'),
trailing: checkboxStatus
    ? Checkbox(
        value: false,
      )
    : null,
)
```